# console.log() nothing shows up

Tags: javascript, node.js, logging, console

Just updated my code and for some reason `console.log()` does not output anything any idea why?

It now returns this:

```
undefined
done
200
null
```

Script:

```
const request = require('request');
const cheerio = require('cheerio');

request('https://kith.com/collections/footwear/products/jbaq4160-140', (error, response, html) => {
    if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
        const $ = cheerio.load(html);

        const output = $(':contains("6")').attr('value');

        console.log(output);
        console.log('done');
    }
});
```

Comment: Maybe there's an error? Or the status code isn't 200...

Comment: Maybe `error` is not "falsey" or `response.statusCode` is not 200?

Comment: Make sure you haven't accidentally typed something into the console's filter field.

Comment: Try adding a `console.log` call before your error and status code checking. This way you can view the status code yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you assume that `(!error && response.statusCode == 200)`. Put two more console.log after the bracket.

```
      request('https://kith.com/collections/footwear/products/jbaq4160-140', (error, response, html) => {

      if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
      const $ = cheerio.load(html);

      const output = $(':contains("4.5")').attr('value');

      console.log(output);
      console.log('done');
    }
    console.log(response.statusCode);
    console.log(error);
});
```

Comment: Thanks that worked, although now I get error 403, any idea on how to bypass that? I will mark it as awnser since it was.

Comment: HTTP 403 means: access forbidden. The url works from a browser but with your code you're not sending any headers so that might explain the 403. Try adding a user-agent header.

 'User-Agent': 'request'

Answer (score 0):

Add a user-agent header like this:

```
var options = {
  headers: {'user-agent': 'request'}
}

 request('https://kith.com/collections/footwear/products/jbaq4160-140', options, function(error, response, html) => {
```

Comment: Awesome but now it returns (look back at question) the element is there for sure.

Answer (score 0):

In your code, replace:

```
const output = $(':contains("4.5")').attr('value');
```

By

```
const output = $
```

I suspect that there is a problem with your expression: `$(':contains("4.5")').attr('value')`